# Как можно ускорить работу for в python?

Tags: python, массивы, vkontakte-api, for

Мне нужно записать всех пользователей чата в массив. Делаю это через инструмент vk api и for, но... он слишком долго считает. Можно ли как-то это ускорить?

```
count_user_in_chat = self.vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id = self.event.object.peer_id)["count"]
chat_users = []

for i in range(count_user_in_chat):
    try: 
        user = self.vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id = self.event.object.peer_id)["profiles"][i]["id"]
        chat_users.append(user)
    except IndexError:
        pass
print(chat_users)
```

Comment: Не for работает долго, а долго выполняется метод getConversationMembers. Вместо того чтобы 100 раз дергать этот метод с одним и тем же аргументом, сохраните результат его вызова один раз, потом из результата получайте нужные данные.

Comment: ааа, вот оно как, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 2 причины:

1. Как сказал @insolor это не for работает долго, а долго выполняется метод getConversationMembers.
2. если у вас python-2.x, то есть не python.3, то можно использовать не `range()`, а `xrange()`. Но это только для второго python.